# Problems with Adding more items to a listview with a holder

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter

I am trying to create a `ListView` with a holder, and adding more items on scroll. The problem is, my adapter doesn't recognize the new items as new. I am very confused at this point. What is wrong here?

A simplified version of my adapters getView method:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final MyHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.empty_item, null);
            holder = new MyHolder();
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            holder.tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);

        } else {
            holder = (MyHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        return convertView;
}
```

MyHolder:

```
class MyHolder {

        public TextView tvTitle;

}
```

So first 3 items goes in the `convertview==null`, but rest of them does not. What might be the issue here?

Comment: what do you mean by this 'my adapter doesn't recognize the new items as new'

Answer (score 0):

**1)** When you add new items to your adapter, you must call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to notifies the attached observers about data changes and refresh your views.

**2)**  Your `if` block (`convertview==null`) will be executed, when there is a need to inflate a new item/layout, otherwise it will call the `else` block to **recycle** an old one.

This is how the [`ListView`'s recycling mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14108676/4224337) work:

[image]